# Using GLEW with Qt 5.x

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glew, oglplus

I am currently trying to get a Qt 5 window and `QOpenGLContext` working with GLEW. Yeah, I know Qt 5 provides its own function wrappings for OpenGL, but since my rendering engine relies on GLEW and supports other window libraries as well, Qt's built-in stuff is not an option.

Now, here is what I got up and running so far:

1. I sub-classed `QWindow` and equipped it with a `QOpenGLContext`. The context is initialized successfully.
2. After initializing `QOpenGLContext`, I (again successfully) call `glewInit()` to initialize GLEW.
3. I am now able to render geometry to the default framebuffer in the exact same way as I do it for other window frameworks (GLFW, to be more precise).

Here comes the tricky part: I am using one of OpenGL's uniform buffer objects to transfer light data to the GPU. As soon as I call `glBufferData()` to initially fill it, I get a segmentation fault. When using my GLFW-based implementation and context initialization, everything works fine. I know that this kind of behavior can be expected for insufficiently initialized OpenGL contexts, but again, setting up `QOpenGLContext` and calling `glewInit()` seems to work just fine.

Here is some code to show what I'm trying to do...

```
QtWindow::QtWindow(QWindow *parent)
 : QWindow(parent) {

  setSurfaceType(QWindow::OpenGLSurface);

  QSurfaceFormat format;
  format.setVersion(4,5);
  format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DeprecatedFunctions);
  format.setSwapBehavior(QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
  format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);

  setFormat(format);

}
```

This should be sufficient to later on get a context of the format I desire. Now, just before the first frame is rendered, I set up the context and GLEW...

```
void QtWindow::init_context() {

  if (!initialized_) {
    context_handler_.init(this);
    initialized_ = true;

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    auto e = glewInit();
    if (e != GLEW_OK) {
      std::cout << "Failed to initialize glew: " 
                << glewGetErrorString(e) << std::endl;
    }

    glGetError();

  }

}
```

I use a small helper class for initializing `QOpenGLContext` as I need to prevent Qt from un-defining GLEW macros:

```
void QtContextHandler::init(QWindow* parent) {
  if (!qt_context_) {
    qt_context_ = new QOpenGLContext(parent);
    qt_context_->setFormat(parent->requestedFormat());

    if (qt_context_->create()) {
      auto format(qt_context_->format());
      std::cout << "Initialized Qt OpenGL context "
                << format.majorVersion() << "."
                << format.minorVersion() << " successfully."
                << std::endl;


      qt_context_->makeCurrent(parent);
    } else {
      std::cout << "Failed to initialize Qt OpenGL context!" 
                << std::endl;
    }

  }
}
```

Here is what I do for setting up the light UBO and what crashes when OpenGL is initialized as shown above. I am using oglplus as a GL wrapper, but since it wraps OpenGL's functions quite tightly, you should get the idea:

```
ubo_.Bind(ogl::Buffer::Target::Uniform);

oglplus::Buffer::Data(oglplus::Buffer::Target::Uniform, sizeof(data), &data, oglplus::BufferUsage::DynamicDraw);
```

Has anyone tried similar approaches and can share their experience? I would appreciate any help since I'm stuck trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Again: The initialization seems to run smoothly and I am even able to create VBOs/VAOs/IBOs for rendering meshes! Only creating the UBO causes a segmentation fault.

**EDIT:**

Okay, here are some new insights. First of all, the segmentation fault only occurs if the uploaded data exceeds a certain size (~90 bytes). In other words, I can render a scene with the Qt-created context using exactly one custom light source. When querying `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE` though, the driver tells me that 64KB are available for uniform blocks (the same holds for GLFW-created contexts). Does anyone have an idea on what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: You say that as soon as you use `glBufferData` you get a seg fault.  Have you checked that `glBufferData` is non-null at that point?

Comment: @G.M. Yes, I checked that. Curiously enough, I tried uploading some dummy data like so `std::array<int, 10> d = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` and `ogl::Buffer::Data(ogl::Buffer::Target::Uniform, sizeof(d), &d, ogl::BufferUsage::DynamicDraw);` and it worked perfectly fine (except the unexpected shader-side behavior, obviously). I am getting the feeling that the data types I use for the light data are getting messed up or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, just in case anyone encounters similar difficulties: I managed to get it working by uploading the UBO data using `glBufferStorage` instead of `glBufferData`. The former is used for creating buffers of immutable size, which is sufficient for my purposes. Still, I don't know what went wrong with `glBufferData` and whether it is a bug in Qt or I initialized the context incorrectly.

Comment: Have you tried this with the later versions of Qt so far? (This thread was wrote a year ago(2016) now is 2017).